# Does removing an Android permission prompt users' consent again?

Tags: android, permissions, dialog, manifest

I am planning to remove an Android permission from my AndroidManifest.xml.

I am curious if users will be notified with a permission dialog again or not when they upgrade the app the to the new version.

Thanks
Niz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it does not prompt the user again if you are requiring less permissions than the previous version.

Comment: i have tried this on one of my apps. I didn't need to have delete cache permissions and removed that in the next update of the app it automatically updated the apps for my devices without prompting a modal.